# Apache RewriteRule in htaccess - Routes are broken

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting

I have a simple structure:

```
Root
|-- [app] (Symfony Application)
|    |-- [app]
|    |-- [bin]
|    |-- [src]
|    |-- [vendor]
|    |-- [web]
|         |-- .htaccess (Symfony htaccess)
|
|-- [wp-admin]
|-- [wp-content]
|-- [wp-include]
|-- .htaccess (Root htaccess)
```

I need following mapping:

```
http://example.com      ==> Wordpress 
http://example.com/app  ==> Symfony Application
```

This is what I have:

## Root htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^app(.*)$ app/web/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## Symfony htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

## Problem:

The problem is that, Symfony routes are not resolved:

> No route found for "GET /"

Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: Are there any limitations to what you can change? For example, if the web hosting provider doesn't give you SSH access or allow changes to the underlying Apache config or modules, or that you can't change the directory structure of your project?

Comment: I have no shell access. I have a solution with `/web` in urls, but I want to get rid of that with a simple solution. I prefer not to breaking up the Symfony's directory structure

Comment: If you have at least some kind of administration tool, you might be able to point a subdomain to the web folder?

Answer (score 1):

This  solution  requires ssh access.

Abandon all solutions based on htaccess rules .  Try to use symbolic  link instead  **ln -s command**

The best idea here  is to put  each project in seperate folder otuside folder where your  domain is pointing (let's name it here as public_html)

```
ROOT
|
-[Symfony]
-[WP]
-[public_html] (folder where your domain is pointing)
```

and now
- remove public_html
- add symbolic link  to wp ( with name of public html)
- include wp create symbolic  link to symfony/web

```
ROOT
|
-[Symfony]
-[WP]
-- [app]  (symbolic link to symfony/web)
-[public_html] (symbolic link to WP )
```

As alternative i think that possible is to redirect request from symfony to wp and then push wp response to user(from symfony) . I seen  solutions  like this ( it's used when you building  new app on top of legacy system ) . But this is more problematic than  symbolic link  ( you can see the idea  here https://www.enotogorsk.ru/en/2014/07/22/symfony-legacy-bridge/)

Comment: Please clearly use standard directory structure (like mine). I don't understand your notation